# Generate SSH KEY from txt file in Docker container

Tags: linux, docker, ssh, dockerfile, remote-access

Hi I have the next Dockerfile for running container:

```
FROM node
RUN apt-get update
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN apt-get install -y openssh-server
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
WORKDIR /home/debian
COPY ./ /home/debian
RUN git init
RUN git clone --branch master https://github.com/SamLProgrammer/LAB1SD.git
WORKDIR /home/debian/LAB1SD
RUN npm install
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

I'm using "docker-entrypoint.sh" to launch ssh service, I would like to do the same to generate an ssh-key (key-gen) but I want this key to be read from a txt file. Something like this:

My "docker-entrypoint.sh" is:

```
#!/bin/bash
service ssh restart
exec "$@"
```

I am trying to achieve something like :

```
#!/bin/bash
service ssh restart
ssh-keygen 'file.txt' // <--- adding something like this (I dont know what command to apply)
exec "$@"
```

Where "file.txt" has the key in the first line

I would be really glad to any suggestion on how to achieve that Please.

Comment: A Docker container usually runs only a single process; its filesystem isn't usually particularly important, and managing ssh credentials is difficult at best.  Does the container need an ssh daemon; why?  Would you open up dedicated ssh daemons for other single processes?

Comment: Do you want to copy your public key (from a text file) inside a docker container?